# Ping event can't be Emitted or received

Tags: node.js, websocket

I used [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) to implement my websocket server and in the api docs i found it has a ping/pong event,however, i couldn't received the event.
server:

```
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    ws.onclose = function () {
        console.log('client disappeared');
    };
    ws.ping('hello');//Send a ping
});
```

client:

```
<script>
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

        function sendMesage() {
            ws.send('hello');
        }

        ws.onopen = function () {
            console.log('connection to server opened');
        };
        ws.onclose = function () {
            console.log('closed');
        }

        ws.onping = function () {
            console.log('ping');
        };// expect to receive ping event
    </script>
```

Comment: no it's not a message, and you must play `ping-pong`, try adding  `on('ping')` and `on('pong')` listeners on both server and client, then emit an ping

Comment: Browser will send pong to server automatically when it receive ping?  i can't add ws.on('ping',function) in client.

Comment: no it won't do it automatically, the client had to send a pong if a ping is received and vice versa. Are you sure you can't add the listener ? you are using the client class from `ws` package right ? if so you should.

Comment: Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object.you can found this [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws).so use the client class from `ws` package?